# New token no name or call sign?

Tags: tokens, polygon, new-blockchain

I created a new token on the Polygon net and got it all worked out, showing in my wallet, and confirmed by etherscan (I did this all in remix). But now if we go to the token in the polygonscan it wont have a name (just shows up as "token") and the callsign is just () blank.

Is there something I am missing? I used the default premade code from the imported OpenZeppelin

Comment: Have you specified the token name and symbol in the token contract that you've deployed ?